# Months are showing numbers 1 to 12 instead of the name of the month

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am writing a code that calculates the average returns of the day but the code I wrote shows the months as number from 1 to 12 instead of the name itself. Below is the code I have written and the output.

This is the code I have written and its output

```py
start_date = '2023-01-01'

end_date = '2023-12-31'

dates_2023 = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1, 32), columns=dates_2023.month.unique())

for date in dates_2023:
    month = date.month
    day = date.day
    df1.loc[day, month] = month_name[month]

df1 = df1.sort_index()

for date in dates_2023:
    month = date.month
    day = date.day
    df1.loc[day, month] = date.strftime('%b')

df1 = df1.sort_index()

df_grouped = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()

for index, row in df_grouped.iterrows():
    month, day = index
    df1.loc[day, month] = row['Daily_returns']

df1
```

[image]

Comment: It says "Jan" and "Jul" in the output. Why do you think it outputs the numbers of the months?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution could be defining a Dictionary in which the value is the number of the month and key would be the name of the month. And whenever you want you can access the key of months.

```
month = {   '01':'January',
        '02':'February',
        '03':'March',
        '04':'April',
        '05':'May',
        '06':'June',
        '07':'July',
        '08':'August',
        '09':'September',
        '10':'October',
        '11':'November',
        '12':'December'     }
```